# Youtube screen has shrunk

Tags: browser, web, cookies, browser-cache

I'm using the Torch browser because my previously-used Firefox had some issues with Youtube; Youtube freezes randomly. Then I switched to Torch and so far it worked without a hassle. But now, today I opened the browser and the Youtube video has shrunk and it is pretty annoying to me. Is there any way I can fix that?

And yes I did clear cookies and caches on both of the browsers

When using Firefox

[image]

When using Torch

[image]

Edit- for journeyman's request ↓

[image]

Comment: what happens when you put it in cinema mode? that's the rectangle at the bottom left, second icon

Comment: On which browser?

Comment: Well, I see it on torch on your screenshot